# Class 'FIRDynamicLinkComponents' not found while integrating FirebaseDynamicLink in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am integrating FirebaseDynamicLink in my cocos2dx-ios project, I have successfully integrated firebase into my iOS project, but while integrating FirebaseDynamicLink, I could not find class `FIRDynamicLinkComponents` into framewok, I also tried using Firebase dynamiclink sample, but found same error there also. Plz help me with this issue.
Here is my podfile content:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'


target 'test-mobile' do
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!

# Pods for test-mobile
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

Waiting for response!

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal, use pod update at the directory of PodFile of your project then you should see something like:

> Installing FirebaseDynamicLinks 2.0.0 (was 1.3.4)

Build again and your problem should be resolved.